# How to select a Set<> attribute from an Entity by CriteriaBuilder

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, criteria

I have this entity:

```
public Entity {

    @JoinTable(name = "entity_equivalents",
            joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "entity_new")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "entity_old")})
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Entity> equivalents;
```

I have been trying to create a CriteriaQuery where I select the equivalents from an Entity, I can't figure out how to create the CriteriaQuery

```
  public Set<Entity> findEquivalents(Entity p1) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    // HERE is the problem
        CriteriaQuery<Set<Entity>> query = cb.createQuery(); // <----
        Root<Entity> root = query.from(Entity.class);
        Expression<Set<Entity>> exx= root.get(Entity_.equivalents);
        query.select(exx); 
        query.where(cb.equal(root.get(Entity_.id), p1.getId()));
        return em.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();

    }
```

I don't want to make the attribute `FetchType.EAGER` or leave the EM opened and fetch the loading while using the instance like `enti.getEquivalents();`

Temporal workaround (until someone guides me to unveil the mysteries of CriteriaQuery):

```
return new HashSet<>(getEntityManager()
.createQuery("SELECT o.equivalents from Entity o where o.id=" + id)
.getResultList());
```

Comment: You have to Join Entity and equivalents. and then get a result list. How would you do that with SQL?

Comment: there are a few ways to do this in SQL, that's not the problem, I could just jump to the table entity_equivalents and `select entity_old where entity_new = ` or make a subquery: `select * from entity where id IN (select entity_old bla bla)`

Comment: So based on your SQL example you should translate this to CriteriaAPI. There are plenty of examples like https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/criteria-api-sub-query.html

Comment: Use `root.join`.